# How do I refresh resources folder of web application?

Tags: file, jsp, tomcat, server, resources

I'm developing a web application in which I want to insert users and be able to display files that they upload via a search option. I can get all of the logic that I need sorted and the files uploaded into the correct directory. However, if I insert a new user into the db, the web app cannot find their file in the directory until I restart the server.

How can I make it so that the resources directory of my web app automatically gets refreshed by the server? I'm developing in Java/JSP and using Tomcat as my server.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're putting the files into the `src/main/resources` folder, then it's being packaged *into the artifact* and then you access them as the classpath resources. Then the next portion of the resources is going to be available after the next packaging.

Instead you should access the Files via usual File System and Absolute or Relative paths.